# I'm getting an error while detecting bottle fill level with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect the filling levels of bottles moving on a conveyor belt with opencv. Since the bottles are colored, I give a white light from the back and determine the liquid contours and measure. I'm getting an error in a certain part of the code. Mistake;

`(contours, areas) = zip(*sorted(zip(contours, areas), key = lambda a:a[1])) ValueError: not enouhg values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`

[For ex photograph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o2lq.png)

When I increase the threshold value in the code, the program runs. But I want this value to remain constant. The reason for this is related to the quality of the contours. Thank you from now.
Source Code:

````
    _, frame = cap.read()
    # hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR.BGR2HSV)

    bottle_gray = cv2.split(frame)[0]
    bottle_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(bottle_gray, (7,7), 0)

    (T, bottle_threshold) = cv2.threshold(bottle_gray, 49.5, 250, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
    bottle_open = cv2.morphologyEx(bottle_threshold, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    contours = cv2.findContours(bottle_open.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
    bottle_clone = frame.copy()
    cv2.drawContours(bottle_clone, contours, 0, (255,0,0), 2)
    areas = [cv2.contourArea(contour) for contour in contours]
    (contours, areas) = zip(*sorted(zip(contours,areas),key = lambda a:a[1]))```
````

Comment: Can't reproduce the stated error with the given code and the provided image. Why do you use the blue channel (`cv2.split(frame)[0]`) instead of proper converting to grayscale? What's your actual idea to get the fill level? Just from your code, that's not clear, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Fix HSV color range
def fixHSVRange(h, s, v):
    return (180 * h / 360, 255 * s / 100, 255 * v / 100)

# Load image
dir = sys.path[0]
im = cv2.imread(dir+'/im.png')

# Convert image to HSV and find empty bottle range
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, fixHSVRange(0, 50, 60), fixHSVRange(5, 100, 100))

# Smooth noise
msk = cv2.medianBlur(msk, 21)

# Invert colors
msk = ~msk

# Find empty space bounderies
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(msk, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnts[1])

# Draw level line
msk = cv2.cvtColor(msk, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.line(msk, (0, y+h), (im.shape[1], y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

# Save output
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/im_msk.png', np.hstack((im, msk)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. @Shamshirasaz.Navid  Would this method be efficient in real time? And in which step of the program should I use this method?

Comment: I do not think this method is heavy :) It depends on what hardware you need to run. This is a prototype that you need to take the time to complete. This is the whole program; It does not need to be located elsewhere. But if you need to work on video frames in real time, you have to change this code.